# Matrix manipulation code performing unknown operations

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am having trouble understanding all of the following code. I think that the middle section of the code that I point out is performing a multiplication, but I am not sure, can someone please explain to me what the middle part of the code is trying to accomplish?

I understand the input and output parts of the array elements, but not the actual manipulations.

I understand this:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
       int i,j,k,n;
       float a[100][200],t;
       cout<<"Enter order of matrix-";
       cin>>n;
       cout<<"Enter elements of matrix"<<endl;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
             cin>>a[i][j];
```

But the following lines are confusing:

```
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          for(j=n;j<2*n;j++)
          {
              if(i==j-n)
                 a[i][j]=1;
             else
                 a[i][j]=0;
           }
       }
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          t=a[i][i];
          for(j=i;j<2*n;j++)
              a[i][j]=a[i][j]/t;
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
             if(i!=j)
             {
                t=a[j][i];
                for(k=0;k<2*n;k++)
                    a[j][k]=a[j][k]-t*a[i][k];
              }
          }
       }
```

Again, the following lines are understandable:

```
cout<<"\n\nInverse matrix\n\n";
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          for(j=n;j<2*n;j++)
             cout<<"\t"<<a[i][j];
          cout<<"\n";
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to invert a matrix. Here is what the code is doing.

Assuming that you have a nxn matrix A, we can create a new nx2n matrix

> B = AI

where I is an nxn identity matrix. The creation of B is what these lines are trying to do:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          for(j=n;j<2*n;j++) // makes sure you are only accessing columns in the right hand part of the matrix
          {
              if(i==j-n)
                 a[i][j]=1;
             else
                 a[i][j]=0;
           }
       }
```

you then perform a series of **row operations** on this 2n wide matrix to get the  identity matrix on the left hand side resulting in a third matrix

> C=ID

where I is again the nxn identity matrix. The creation of C through row operations is what this part of the code is trying to do: (though I won't speak to the correctness of the algorithm that is being used as it has been a while since I have done this and I typically just use an SVD algorithm for inverses)

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) //transform B matrix into C matrix
       {
          t=a[i][i];
          for(j=i;j<2*n;j++)
              a[i][j]=a[i][j]/t;
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
             if(i!=j)
             {
                t=a[j][i];
                for(k=0;k<2*n;k++)
                    a[j][k]=a[j][k]-t*a[i][k];
              }
          }
       }
```

now when you successfully complete the row operations and get the identity matrix on the left hand side of the C matrix, it turns out that the nxn D matrix that makes up the right hand side of the C matrix is the inverse of A. so we have

> AD = I

which is why that last bit of code only grabs the right hand side of what I called the C matrix.

that's what your code is trying to do. If you want to understand more about the theory behind it, I would take a look at the "Numerical Recipes in C" book. It's the gold standard for this kind of thing and freely available online. http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.html

Comment: is there a more simple method to do this?

Comment: not in general. if your matrix is 2x2 you can use something called cramer's rule, but in general you are stuck with this or "singular value decomposition" to get a pseudoinverse which is significantly more involved. the numerical recipes book has SVD so you can compare the complexity if you want.